# How to install ubuntu on my Xperia Arc S? (Please note I love this handset so I have neither rooted or flashed)

Tags: 12.04, ubuntu-for-android

Please note I am novice at this installation. Please point me to answers not to other forums.

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1):

That device is not supported. Ubuntu 12.04 is an operating system conceived for desktop and laptop computers with large form factors. Future Ubuntu releases will eventually support natively [a wider range of devices with different form factors](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/UnityNextSpec); you must be patient for a bit longer.

Is it possible [to preview Ubuntu on a handset with Ubuntu Touch](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Touch/DualBootInstallation), but only on Nexus 4 devices.